# Child Output triggering wrong observabe and said observable received wrong data

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

So I've been going on about this for a while and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have a child component, which is a modal. The child component has a search bar, which when used emits to the parent, who in turns uses a ngrx store facade to query data. The parent subscribes to all facade observables on init. The parent then passes the data to the child component to render.

Expected behavior:

1. Search in child, send query string to parent
2. Parent receives emit and queries facade with the string
3. Facade dispatches an action to the store, which runs an effect to get the new data.
4. As parent is subscribed to facade observable, should receive updated data and pass it to child.
5. Child renders new data.

Current behavior:

1. Search in child, sends query string to parent (success)
2. Parent receives emit and queries facade with the string (success)
3. Facade dispatches an action to the store, which runs an effect to the new data (success).
4. Parent receives data, but pipes it through the wrong observable first and then through the intended observable (failure).
5. Child renders new data, but data behind modal is broken (failure).

Essentially on step 4, the emit from the child triggers both of the subscriptions in 1. below. The first one receives the string, and receives data which is from Device[] type, passes it to the list component, which breaks, while the second one received data from Device[] type as well and renders properly.

Posting snippets of the code:

1. Parent

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-marketplace',
    templateUrl: './marketplace.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./marketplace.component.sass'],
})
export class MarketplaceComponent {
    public limit: number = 18;
    public offset: number = 0;

    public postings!: Posting[] | null;
    public devices!: Device[] | null;

    constructor(
        public modal: ModalService,
        private postingFacade: PostingFacade,
        private userFacade: UserFacade
    ) {
        this.postingFacade.postingData$.subscribe({
            next: (data: Posting[] | null) => (this.postings = data),
            error: (err: string | null) => console.log(err),
        });
        this.postingFacade.devicesData$.subscribe({
            next: (data: Device[] | null) => (this.devices = data),
            error: (err: string | null) => console.log(err),
        });
    }

    searchPostings(query: string): void {
        this.limit = 18;
        this.postingFacade.queryPostings(query, this.limit, this.offset);
    }

    fetchDeviceList(query: string): void {
        this.postingFacade.queryDevices(query, 10);
    }

    fetchDeviceDetails(key: string): void {
        this.postingFacade.getDeviceDetails(key);
    }
}
```

2. Child

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-create',
    templateUrl: './create.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create.component.sass'],
})
export class CreateComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    public display$!: Observable<boolean>;

    @Input() user!: User | null;
    @Input() devices!: Device[] | null;
    @Input() deviceDetails!: Device | null;
    @Output() requestDeviceList = new EventEmitter<string>();

    @ViewChild('searchInput') searchDevice!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

    constructor(private modal: ModalService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.display$ = this.modal.watch();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        fromEvent(this.searchDevice.nativeElement, 'input')
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(1000),
                distinctUntilChanged(),
                map((e: Event) => (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
            )
            .subscribe({
                next: (res) => {
                    this.deviceDetails = null;
                    this.requestDeviceList.emit(res);
                },
                error: (err) => console.log(err),
            });
    }
```

3. Facade

```
@Injectable()
export class PostingFacade {
    constructor(private readonly store: Store<PostingState>) {}

    public readonly postingData$: Observable<Posting[] | null> = this.store.pipe(
        select(postingSelectors.getPostings)
    );

    public readonly devicesData$: Observable<Device[] | null> = this.store.pipe(
        select(postingSelectors.getPostingDevices)
    );

    public initPostingsData(): void {
        this.store.dispatch(postingActions.PostingInit({ limit: 18, offset: 0 }));
    }

    public loadMorePostings(limit: number, offset: number): void {
        this.store.dispatch(postingActions.PostingLoadMore({ limit, offset }));
    }

    public queryPostings(query: string, limit: number, offset: number): void {
        this.store.dispatch(postingActions.PostingSearch({ query, limit, offset }));
    }

    public queryDevices(query: string, limit: number): void {
        this.store.dispatch(postingActions.PostingLoadDevices({ query, limit }));
    }

    public getDeviceDetails(key: string): void {
        this.store.dispatch(postingActions.PostingLoadDeviceDetails({ key }));
    }

}
```

4. Effects

```
    public readonly getPostings$: Observable<any> = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(PostingActionNames.PostingInit),
            map(({ limit, offset }) => PostingActions.PostingInit({ offset, limit })),
            switchMap(({ limit, offset }) =>
                this.postingService
                    .getPostings(limit, offset)
                    .pipe(
                        map((data: Posting[]) => PostingActions.PostingInitSuccess({ data }))
                    )
            ),
            catchError((error: string | null) =>
                of(PostingActions.PostingInitFailure({ error }))
            )
        )
    );

    public readonly searchDevices$: Observable<any> = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(PostingActionNames.PostingLoadDevices),
            map(({ query, limit }) =>
                PostingActions.PostingLoadDevices({ query, limit })
            ),
            switchMap(({ query, limit }) =>
                this.postingService
                    .searchDevices(query, limit)
                    .pipe(
                        map((data: Device[]) =>
                            PostingActions.PostingLoadDevicesSuccess({ data })
                        )
                    )
            ),
            catchError((error: string | null) =>
                of(PostingActions.PostingLoadDevicesFailure({ error }))
            )
        )
    );
```

5. Reducer

```
export const _postingReducer = createReducer(
    initialPostingState,
    on(postingActions.PostingInit, (state) => ({
        ...state,
        loaded: false,
        error: null,
    })),
    on(postingActions.PostingInitSuccess, (state, { data }) => ({
        ...state,
        postings: data,
        loaded: true,
        error: null,
    })),
    on(postingActions.PostingInitFailure, (state, { error }) => ({
        ...state,
        loaded: false,
        error,
    })),
    on(postingActions.PostingLoadDevices, (state) => ({
        ...state,
        loaded: false,
        error: null,
    })),
    on(postingActions.PostingLoadDevicesSuccess, (state, { data }) => ({
        ...state,
        devices: data,
        loaded: true,
        error: null,
    })),
    on(postingActions.PostingLoadDevicesFailure, (state, { error }) => ({
        ...state,
        loaded: false,
        error,
    })),
}

export function postingReducer(
    state: PostingState | undefined,
    action: Action
) {
    return _postingReducer(state, action);
}
```

6. Selectors

```
export const getPostings = createSelector(
    getPostingState,
    (state: PostingState) => state.postings
);

export const getPostingDevices = createSelector(
    getPostingState,
    (state: PostingState) => state.devices
);
```

7. Services

```
    getPostings(limit: number, offset: number): Observable<any> {
        this.http
            .post(
                `${server}/postings/list`,
                { limit, offset },
                {
                    headers: this.headers,
                }
            )
            .subscribe((res) => this.request.next(res));
        return this.request;
    }

    searchDevices(query: string, limit: number): Observable<any> {
        this.http
            .post(
                `${server}/device/list/search/?query=${query}`,
                { limit },
                {
                    headers: this.headers,
                }
            )
            .subscribe((res) => this.request.next(res));
        return this.request;
    }
```

8. State

```
export const POSTING_FEATURE_KEY = 'posting';

export const initialPostingState: PostingState = {
    postings: null,
    postingsDetails: null,
    devices: null,
    devicesDetails: null,
    create: null,
    user: null,
    loaded: false,
    error: null,
};

export interface PostingState {
    postings: Posting[] | null;
    postingsDetails: Posting | null;
    devices: Device[] | null;
    devicesDetails: Device | null;
    create: Posting | null;
    user: User | null;
    loaded: boolean;
    error: null | string;
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code.  It will be easier for others to help if you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 main issues in the code:

**1. You never unsubscribe in your components**

You create memory leaks and callbacks keep running. Please use methods like `take`/`takeUntil` rxjs operators or `async` pipe.

**2. You have some kind of request subject**

```
getPostings(limit: number, offset: number): Observable<any> {
    this.http
        .post(
            `${server}/postings/list`,
            { limit, offset },
            {
                headers: this.headers,
            }
        )
        .subscribe((res) => this.request.next(res));
    return this.request;
}

searchDevices(query: string, limit: number): Observable<any> {
    this.http
        .post(
            `${server}/device/list/search/?query=${query}`,
            { limit },
            {
                headers: this.headers,
            }
        )
        .subscribe((res) => this.request.next(res));
    return this.request;
}
```

Those lines are just weird and so wrong. You really should remove that subject, type the requests and return the data directly. Currently you will subscribe to an subject *both* responses are stored into which leads to your behavior.

Those methods should look like this:

```
getPostings(limit: number, offset: number): Observable<Posting[]> {
    return this.http.post<Posting[]>(
            `${server}/postings/list`,
            { limit, offset },
            { headers: this.headers },
        );
}

searchDevices(query: string, limit: number): Observable<Device[]> {
    return this.http.post<Device[]>(
            `${server}/device/list/search/?query=${query}`,
            { limit },
            { headers: this.headers },
        );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the refactoring of the services solved the issue (removing the subject). Can you please clarify more on the first point?